# How to convert List<String> to int type in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am a beginner in flutter how do i convert list of string into int. Below is the example code

```
var data="18:00";
List<String> dataList = data.split(':');
print(datalist[0]);
print(datalist[1]);
```

Output will be 18 and 00 under 18, so how do i get this 18 and 00 in int type.

Comment: `int.parse(datalist[0]);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert your list of `String` into a list of `int` by mapping through each element and parsing to an `int`.

```
  List<int> dataListAsInt = dataList.map((data) => int.parse(data)).toList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just parse your data with **int.parse(//your data)**

```
var data="18:00";
List<String> dataList = data.split(':');
print(int.parse(dataList[0]));
print(int.parse(dataList[1]));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this like:

```
var data="18:00";
List<String> dataList = data.split(':');    
for(String s in datalist){
  int a=int.parse(s);
  print(a);
}
```

hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

How to convert string to int

```
int.parse(data.split(':')) // this is how
```